# python replace \r\n in elements of array

Tags: python, arrays, replace, element

I have a list. one element is a large string containing `\r\n`. I want to remove it so that when I write elements to a new file a new line will begin when new list is written into it.

Somehow `replace("\r\n","")`, does not work.

For example:

```
['1','Smth\r\nmoretext']
```

This has to be in a new file:

> 1,smthmoretext

Thank you

Comment: Show exactly how you tried to use `replace("\r\n", "")` and what happened vs. what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do an operation on each element in a list, and put the results in a new list.

```
items = ['abc', 'abc\r\ndef', 'foo\r\n bar\r\n']
newItems = [s.replace('\r\n', '') for s in items]
print newItems
# ['abc', 'abcdef', 'foo bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with replace? How do you call the replace-function?

I seems to work:

```
>>> 'Smth\r\nmoretext'.replace("\r\n", "")
'Smthmoretext'
```

To replace all elements in a list:

```
lst = ['1','Smth\r\nmoretext']
lst = [txt.replace("\r\n", "") for txt in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're treating strings and arrays interchangeably.
Don't do that.

This will handle the replacement for you

```
>>> old = ['1','Smth\r\nmoretext']
>>> new = [i.replace("\r\n","") for i in old]
>>> print new
['1', 'Smthmoretext']
```

not sure how you want to write

```
>>> open('file-a.txt',w).write('\n'.join(new))
>>> open('file-b.txt',w).write(','.join(new))
```

though you could also do:

```
>>> new = ','.join(old)
>>> new.replace("\r\n", "")
>>> print new
>>> 1,Smthmoretext
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet would yield the result you seem to require:

```
xs = ['1', 'Smth\r\nmoretext']
result = ','.join(map(lambda x: x.replace('\r\n',''), xs)).lower()
```

The `map` built-in function is used to apply the anonymous `lambda` function on each element of the `xs` array, where the `\r\n` substring is removed.

The `','.join(...)` command then takes each element of the resulting array, and glues them together with commas in between elements.

Finally, we call '.lower()' on the final resulting string in order to yield the all-lower case string '1,smthmoretext' string that you wanted.

An alternative could be:

```
result = ','.join([ x.replace('\r\n','') for x in xs ]).lower()
```

Or, on several lines:

```
result = [ x.replace('\r\n','') for x in xs ]
result = ','.join(result)
result = result.lower()
```

Choose what makes most sense to yourself, but also, more importantly, what may be easier to read for those whom will maintain your code (which might be yourself in 6 months time).